# gpg no default secret key error using maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, gnupg

I am trying to publish my maven project in the Central Repository and I need to sign my artifacts. I have downloaded and installed gpg and created my keyring. When I run a "maven clean deploy" in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
gpg: no default secret key: No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
```

I have searched online and I am not sure what to do. The only reference about gpg in my pom.xml file is

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you work out the solution for this?

Comment: I believe the problem was with my settings.xml file. I will check in my other computer and let you know what the change was.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, what did you do to resolve the problem ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This was a long time ago and I cannot remember exactly what I did to fix it. Something that I do remember is that I had a spelling mistake in my `settings` file. Look at my answer below to what my file looks like right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This questions was asked a long time ago and I cannot remember exactly what I did to fix it. I do remember I had a spelling mistake in my `settings.xml` file. This is what I changed in my file:

```
<profile>
  <id>sign</id>
  <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
      <gpg.passphrase>password</gpg.passphrase>
  </properties> 
</profile>
```

This now works.

Answer (score 22):

I just encountered the same error message. In my case it was caused by the key being expired as this command shows:

```
six-58:tmp hot$ gpg --list-keys
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
/Users/hot/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-----------------------------
pub   2048R/236D3BEF 2016-12-30 [expired: 2018-12-30]
uid                  Holger Thurow <...@gmail.com>
```

Note the "[expired: 2018-12-30]".

This is what I did to solve the problem:

```
six-58:tmp hot$ gpg --edit-key 236D3BEF
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.19; Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret key is available.

pub  2048R/236D3BEF  created: 2016-12-30  expired: 2018-12-30  usage: SC  
                     trust: ultimate      validity: expired
sub  2048R/450709B5  created: 2016-12-30  expired: 2018-12-30  usage: E   
[ expired] (1). Holger Thurow <...@gmail.com>

gpg> 1

pub  2048R/236D3BEF  created: 2016-12-30  expired: 2018-12-30  usage: SC  
                     trust: ultimate      validity: expired
sub  2048R/450709B5  created: 2016-12-30  expired: 2018-12-30  usage: E   
[ expired] (1)* Holger Thurow <...@gmail.com>

gpg> expire
Changing expiration time for the primary key.
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
         0 = key does not expire
      <n>  = key expires in n days
      <n>w = key expires in n weeks
      <n>m = key expires in n months
      <n>y = key expires in n years
Key is valid for? (0) 
Key does not expire at all
Is this correct? (y/N) y

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Holger Thurow <...@gmail.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID 236D3BEF, created 2016-12-30


pub  2048R/236D3BEF  created: 2016-12-30  expires: never       usage: SC  
                     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  2048R/450709B5  created: 2016-12-30  expired: 2018-12-30  usage: E   
[ultimate] (1)* Holger Thurow <...@gmail.com>

gpg> save
```

See "Dealing with Expired Keys" described in detail [here](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/working-with-pgp-signatures.html).

Answer (score 5):

You cannot sign artifacts because you have no GPG key. The solution is to [create one](http://keyring.debian.org/creating-key.html).

Comment: But I did create one. It is in my .gnugp folder

Answer (score 0):

Note: Eclipse 4.23 (Q1 2022) will now allow for:

> ### Manage trusted PGP keys
>
> The **`Install/Update > Trust`** preference page allows to add or remove PGP public keys that are trusted by default during installation process.
>
> Artifacts signed with a secret key matching one of the trusted public PGP key will install without prompting the Trust dialog.

That could help maven when run from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with replacing executing the IntelliJ IDEA maven configuration with executing it in git-bash.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).