# gpg: signing failed: secret key not available

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, jenkins, gnupg

I have an artifact hosted on maven. my setup on the local windows machine has been working perfectly; `maven, gpg keys` name it. upto now I can do `'mvn clean deploy'` and my artifact gets signed and released very successfully. 
Enter continous integration with jenkins hosted on an ubuntu server. I successfully install gpg on ubuntu via putty. Since I already have versions of the artifact on maven signed with my gpg keys, I should continue using them right?
So, I use winscp to transfer the gnupg folder and all its contents to ubuntu. Indeed when I run `gpg --list-keys`, I can see my key information (I only have one key configured). I am thinking, this, is a sign that my configuration on ubuntu is successful.
According to an answer to 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885887/gpg-no-default-secret-key-error-using-maven) I should take that there are no keys configured on ubuntu. So why would `gpg --list-keys` work??
When jenkins is trying to deploy the artifact, the "`sign`" goal fails and `maven-gpg-plugin` reports this:

```
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
```

and the build fails, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the build service running under another user? If so, make sure to import the key to the service user's GnuPG directory (`sudo -su username` or similar solution).

Comment: @JensErat, after reading your  comment, I cleared the .gnupg directory on Ubuntu and set out afresh to do importation following [this tutorial](https://www.phildev.net/pgp/gpg_moving_keys.html). Everything worked well. However, I still don't see any change

Comment: @JensErat, I learnt quite late that the build service was running on a different user. I did `sudo -su username`, tried to `--list-keys` but got a write access error. so, I used root account to give this user access to `.gnupg` directory, exported the keys and imported them into the right user's account. All this has not helped me yet.

Comment: I don't know exactly how Maven performs the signing, and cannot really help you with the issue. Make sure to learn how exactly GnuPG is called under which user, make sure to import the key to this very user, and be aware that GnuPG is very picky about permissions if they're given too broadly (usually, only the user itself should be able to read and write, and no other).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful insights, I did all the above involving `user`. The only other step needed was a config file for maven-gpg-plugin to locate the default key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. The only thing I was missing was the `settings.xml` file for my particular `maven` project. I had to find out where maven looks for this file from while building my project (usin `mvn -X`). Somehow Ubuntu did not create it, so I had to create one for myself and put in the relevant `gpg` properties. After this, everything worked like a breeze.